# How do I print an expanded regex in unexpanded form?

Tags: regex, perl

Is it possible to print a regex created using expanded notation (`qr/.../x`) in non-expanded form? For example:

```
my $decimal = qr/
  (?=\d|\.\d)  # look-ahead to ensure at least one of the optional parts matches
  \d*          # optional whole digits
  (?:\.\d*)?   # optional decimal point and fractional digits
/x;

say $decimal;
```

I want this to be printed as `(?=\d|\.\d)\d*(?:\.\d*)?`.

I could write a parser to strip out the non-functional portions but that would be replicating what perl already does and I'd probably get some of the non-trivial cases wrong.

(Yes, this seems a bit silly. I have a use case where I need to print a lot of messages like `matched <pattern>` and I'd like to limit messages to a single line while allowing expanded notation to be used for patterns.)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202448/discussion-on-question-by-michael-carman-how-do-i-print-an-expanded-regex-in-une).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Perl doesn't provide such a utility. It parses regex patterns; it doesn't generate them. The stringification of the object is the exact string provided to the parser, wrapped in a `(?:...)` that accounts for the flags. The string provided to the parser is the post-interpolation literal minus the delimiters.<sup>[1]</sup>

That said, this would be trivial to do with a regex parser.

There is [YAPE::Regex](https://metacpan.org/pod/YAPE::Regex), but it hasn't been updated in a long time. For example, it doesn't support the `(?^:...)` found in the stringification of regex in modern version of Perl.

There is also [Regexp::Parser](https://metacpan.org/pod/Regexp::Parser). It's newer, but it doesn't support `(?^:...)` either! But if we were to work around that, it would be be perfect since naturally ignores whitespace and comments! All we need to do is parse the pattern and get a stringifiction from the parse tree.

Finally, there's [Regexp::Parsertron](https://metacpan.org/pod/Regexp::Parsertron). It's the newest, and it does support `(?^:...)`, but it doesn't distinguish whitespace and comments from "exact matches" tokens.

So let's use Regexp::Parser.<sup>[2]</sup>

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw( say );

use Regexp::Parser qw( );

{
   @ARGV == 1
      or die("usage\n");

   my $re = $ARGV[0];

   # R::P doesn't support «(?^:...)», so we'll
   # provide a backwards-compatible stringification.
   $re =~ s{^\(\?\^(\w*):}{
      my %on = map { $_ => 1 } split //, $1;
      my $on  = join "", grep  $on{$_}, qw( i m s x );
      my $off = join "", grep !$on{$_}, qw( i m s x );
      "(?$on-$off:"
   }e;

   my $parser = Regexp::Parser->new($re);
   my $roots = $parser->root
      or die($parser->errmsg);

   say join "", map $_->visual, @$roots;
}
```

Test:

```
$ despace_re '(?^x:
   (?=\d|\.\d)  # look-ahead to ensure at least one of the optional parts matches
   \d*          # optional whole digits
   (?:\.\d*)?   # optional decimal point and fractional digits
)'
(?x-ims:(?=\d|\.\d)\d*(?:\.\d*)?)
```

---

1. `\Q`, `\u` and similar are done at the same stage at interpolation. `\N{...}` is resolved to `\N{U+...}` in order to immortalize the current charnames settings. Other escapes such as `\x27`, `\x{0000027}`, `\\` and `\/` are preserved character for character.
2. A solution based on YAPE::Regex was used in [an earlier revision](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/58884612/3) of this answer.

Comment: Add your find with `re::regex_pattern($qr)`?  That does give them a way to get what they need, or close to that, perhaps with a simple sub

Comment: @zdim, I don't see how `re::regex_pattern($qr)` helps at all.

Comment: It removes the surrounding stuff (`(?: )`) ... that's somethin'.  The spaces are thorny I realize -- if there's `x` mod there can still be legal spaces inside `[ ]` (one example I could recall, there's probably more) ... but they could strip newlines manually? Then there'd be an acceptable printout?

Comment: @zdim, But removing that stuff is a bad thing. It could change the pattern to mean something else. It's there because it's a significant part of the pattern.

Comment: @zdim, Four cases where whitespace is significant when using `/x`:  `\␠`, `[␠]`, `(?-x:␠)` and `(?-x)␠`. There might be more.

Comment: yup, you're right ... looks like they can't touch spaces (I was talking about cleaning up if there's `/x` modifier but even that's off limits) without writing a full parser ...

Comment: @zdim, Definitely. Consider `\␠`: Is it really `\\␠`? If you look for `(?-x)␠`, did you look for `(?-ix)␠` and `(?^u)␠` too? Well, you might need a full parser, but close. (And it might be easier to write a full parser than trying to figure out what the leave out!)

Comment: Right -- one would have to play the regex engine a little.  I guess that would mean that they'd have to settle with having spaces, `/x`-ed or not ... but `re::regexp_pattern($qr)` may still be useful.

Comment: @zdim: While `regexp_pattern()` is interesting, I don't really care about the `(?:...)` wrapper with the flags; it's the newlines and comments that are problematic for me. I was mildly surprised that they didn't get discarded when building regex object.

Comment: @MichaelCarman Yeah, I didn't get that at first (sloppy initial reading, sorry) ... i do find it surprising that irrelevant things aren't dropped from the operational form of the pattern. And parsing those spaces, or even firstly newlines, seems outright nasty: how does one decide whether it's the pattern or source code format?